# SQLite query with multiple choice

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i'm will be wanna get rows than contains one of arguments of my string.
I have string as: "One,Two,Three,". I wanna get cursor with all data from table, that have element from this string ( For example, my find String is my string "rock,is,dead" and i wanna get rows that field contains: "rock".
Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Your_Table WHERE 'rock,is,dead' LIKE '%' || String_Column || '%'
```

For more efficient lookups, you need to split up your search string so that the words can be checked individually, which allows the database to use index lookups (if you have an index):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Your_Table WHERE String_Column IN ('rock', 'is', 'dead')
```

(Please note that plain comparisons, unlike `LIKE`, are case sensitive, unless you use a different collation.)

Comment: how i can write your query in this way?
db.query(DBHelper.TAG_TABLE, null,null,null,null,null,null);???
Thanks